# How to find display scaling factor on retina/4k displays?

Tags: macos, opengl, glfw

I have a big display operating in scaled mode for bigger text. This scaling isn't being reported to my program which is an OpenGL app using GLFW for windowing. All my geometry is half-sized and offset by half the height of the actual viewport. Here's a set of images showing the problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbriu.jpg. How can I get the value of the scaling so I can correct my projection?

Comment: BTW, multiplying my viewport's width and height by 2 solves the problem, but I need a (cross platform) way of determining the scaling factor.

Comment: How do you determine the viewport size? From the GLFW docs: "While the size of a window is measured in screen coordinates, OpenGL works with pixels. The size you pass into glViewport, for example, should be in pixels and not screen coordinates. On some platforms screen coordinates and pixels are the same, but this is not the case on all platforms supported by GLFW. There is a second set of functions to retrieve the size in pixels of the framebuffer of a window." I think this adresses exactly what you see here.

Comment: For the viewport size I just ask GLFW what the window size is. This is the problem - GLFW is giving me screen coordinates and glViewport takes pixels, which may or may not be 2x GLFW's window size. I'm not sure how to query for this scaling factor since it is outside of GLFW and OpenGL.

Comment: No, it is not outside of the scope of GLFW. I forgot to add the linke to the qutoe above, which exactly contains the functions you need to query the framebuffer pixel size suitable for glViewport: [GLFW window framebuffer size](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_fbsize)

Comment: @derhass - sorry if my text seemed harsh, that was not meant, thank you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [glfwGetFramebufferSize](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga0e2637a4161afb283f5300c7f94785c9) to get the actual size of the window in pixels on displays that use window coordinates that don't match pixels. Then pass those values to glViewport.